# ¿Cómo puedo validar si existen varios archivos en un directorio o ruta de mi servidor?

Tags: php, php7

*Que tal, tengo varias imágenes en un directorio de mi servidor, pero solo quisiera validar si existen unas cuantas, ¿Cómo puedo hacerle para validar si existe mas de un archivo en un directorio?.*

**Tengo este código, pero es para validar un solo archivo:**

```
<?php
  $directorio = "/ruta/ruta/imagen.jpg"

  if(file_exists($directorio)) {

     echo "la imagen existe";

  }else{
     echo "la imagen no existe";
  }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Variable de estado, quedará como TRUE si todas las imágenes del array existen en el server
$todas_validadas = TRUE;
//array con las rutas de las imágenes que necesitas validar
$array_imagenes = array(
    "/ruta/ruta/imagen.jpg",
    "/ruta/ruta/imagen2.jpg",
    "/ruta/ruta/imagen3.jpg",
    "/ruta/ruta/imagen4.jpg"
);

//Recorremos el array y comprobamos 1 a 1 si la imagen existe en el server
foreach($array_imagenes as $index => $imagen){  
    if(!file_exists($imagen)) {
        //Si al menos 1 imagen no existe en el server, determinamos que todas_validadas es falso
        $todas_validadas = FALSE;
    }
}
```

?>

A partir de esto puedes crear una función que pase como parámetro el array de imágenes y que retorne el valor de $todas_validadas.